# GDB: Print the value of memory address

Tags: gdb

According to https://www.ethicalhacker.net/columns/heffner/intro-to-assembly-and-reverse-engineering

```
mov 0xffffffb4,0x1
```

> moves the number 1 into 0xffffffb4.

So, I decided to test this on my own.
In GDB, x  is the command to print the value of memory address.
However, when I run

```
x 0x00000000004004fc
```

I'm not getting the value of 133 (decimal) or 85 (hexadecimal)

Instead, I'm getting 0x85f445c7. Any idea what is this?

```
me@box:~/c$ gdb -q test
Reading symbols from test...done.
(gdb) l
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3       int main(){
4               int a = 1;
5               int b = 13;
6               int c = 133;
7               printf("Value of C : %d\n",c);
8               return 0;
9       }
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400503: file test.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/me/c/test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:7
7               printf("Value of C : %d\n",c);
(gdb)
```

Disassemble

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004e6 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004e7 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004ea <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x00000000004004ee <+8>:     movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004f5 <+15>:    movl   $0xd,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004fc <+22>:    movl   $0x85,-0xc(%rbp)
=> 0x0000000000400503 <+29>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400506 <+32>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000000000400508 <+34>:    mov    $0x4005a4,%edi
   0x000000000040050d <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400512 <+44>:    callq  0x4003c0 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400517 <+49>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040051c <+54>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040051d <+55>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x 0x00000000004004fc
0x4004fc <main+22>:     0x85f445c7
(gdb)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to print. If you want to print c then type `print c`. If you want to print hex equivalent, type `p/x c`

Comment: If you want the memory address of variable `c`,  `p&c` would get the addre ss.   What makes you think that `0x00000000004004` is memory address oc `c`?  That address looks more like memory address of assembly code and  `0x85f445c7`represents the hexa representation of machine code.

Comment: @Rishi, my question was "What is 0x85f445c7".
I've no problem to get c value or the memory address of c. Thanks.

(gdb) p c
$1 = 133
(gdb) p &c
$2 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe564
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe564
0x7fffffffe564: 0x00000085
(gdb) x /d 0x7fffffffe564
0x7fffffffe564: 133
(gdb)

Comment: Thanks @Nguaial, that was the answer that I'm looking for.

" 0x85f445c7represents the hexa representation of machine code."

Is there any way to convert "0x85f445c7" to human readable code?

Answer (score 6):

**;DRTL**

To print a value in GDB use print or (p in short form) command.

in your command

> x 0x00000000004004fc

You have missed `p` command. You have to use `x` with `p` command pair to print value as hexadecimal format, like below:

```
(gdb) p/x 0x00000000004004fc
```

If the memory address is some pointer to some structure then you have to cast the memory location before using the pointer. For example,

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next
};
```

is some structure and you have the address of that structure pointer, then to view the contents of that memory location you have to use

```
(gdb) p *(struct node *) 0x00000000004004fc
```

Answer (score 0):

Notable:

The command

> x 0x00000000004004fc

Will look at the instruction and related data for this instruction:

> 0x00000000004004fc <+22>:    movl   $0x85,-0xc(%rbp)

... as you can see that the left column (address) is equal to the value used for the command (the address to read)

In the instruction `0x85` is clearly the destination address for the `mov`, and reflected in the printed value; `0x85f445c7` - which stored as MSB (most significant byte) at the address.